# Can AWS Lambda locally be debugged locally from Cloud events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-lambda

I have a lambda and I can test locally with set inputs.
What I would like to do is debug the lambda locally when it gets events from an Event Bus in the Cloud, is that possible?
I don't want to deploy the lambda until I have tested it in the environment it will be deployed to, it will affect other people.

Comment: One option, which may work depending on the events you care about, would be to setup Event Bus to publish events to a Kinesis stream (in addition to whatever else it's doing).  Then you could test your Lambda code by writing a driver script to pull the event from the Kinesis stream, and call the Lambda entry point with that data.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure is that you can enable Logs in your Code and can debug from that. If code is written in Python. **logging** Library can be used.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is my only way of debugging when run in the cloud. Thanks,